# Vector rules used on del operators

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator

I know you can use vector rules [BAC CAB and $ \vec a \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c)  = \vec c \cdot (\vec a \times \vec b)$] on del operator as long as you keep track of what terms each $\nabla$ is acting on.

You can do this for $\nabla \times (\vec a \times \vec b) $:

$\nabla \times (\vec a \times \vec b) = \overset{\downarrow}{\vec a}(\nabla \cdot \overset{\downarrow}{\vec b}) - \overset{\downarrow}{\vec b} (\nabla \cdot \overset{\downarrow}{\vec a}) \\
  = (\vec b \cdot \nabla) \overset{\downarrow}{\vec a} + \vec a (\nabla \cdot \overset{\downarrow}{\vec b}) - (\vec a \cdot \nabla) \overset{\downarrow}{\vec b} - \vec b(\nabla \cdot \overset{\downarrow}{\vec a}).$

For $\nabla \cdot (\vec a \times \vec b)$ you'll have:

$\nabla \cdot (\vec a \times \vec b) = \overset{\downarrow}{\vec b} \cdot (\nabla \times \overset{\downarrow}{\vec a})$

But how do say when $\nabla$ only acts on $\vec b$ the term will be $- \vec a \cdot (\nabla \times \overset{\downarrow}{\vec b})$?

Or for $\nabla(\vec a \cdot \vec b)$:

$\nabla(\vec a \cdot \vec b) = \overset{\downarrow}{\vec a} \times (\nabla \times \overset{\downarrow}{\vec b}) + \overset{\downarrow}{\vec b}(\overset{\downarrow}{\vec a} \cdot \nabla)$

How do proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\diffthis[1]{\overset{\downarrow}{#1}}
$Let $L(v; a, b)$ be a function of vectors $v, a, b$ which is linear in $v$. Then as a generalization of the product rule
$$
  L(\nabla; \diffthis a, \diffthis b) = L(\nabla; \diffthis a, b) + L(\nabla; a, \diffthis b).
$$
So for example
$$
  \nabla\cdot(\diffthis a\times\diffthis b) = \nabla\cdot(\diffthis a\times b) + \nabla\cdot(a\times\diffthis b).
$$
Now using the triple product cycle identity the first term becomes
$$
  \nabla\cdot(\diffthis a\times b) = b\cdot(\nabla\times\diffthis a)
$$
and the second term becomes
$$
  \nabla\cdot(a\times\diffthis b) = a\cdot(\diffthis b\times\nabla) = -a\cdot(\nabla\times\diffthis b)
$$
so altogether
$$
  \nabla\cdot(\diffthis a\times\diffthis b) = b\cdot(\nabla\times\diffthis a) - a\cdot(\nabla\times\diffthis b)
$$

Comment: @Artin8476 It's the same exact idea. I don't think there's anything to gain by me writing it out.